# Pass array keys and values to Mysql Query String

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, function, foreach

I have an array represents WHERE clause of my SQL query.

```
$qWhere= array("cName" => "Turgay Metal", "cTelephone" => "5556162");
```

my function is: (simplified)

```
<?php
function getAll($tableName,$qWhere="") {
$qWhere = $qWhere == "" ? $qWhere : (" WHERE " . $qWhere);  
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $tableName $qWhere";}
```

So i need to write another function to kinda serialize array with `foreach` as `$k = '$v'`  and then join " AND " then return the string. Finally supply the string into main function:

```
function arr2sql($qWhere) {
    foreach ($qWhere as $key=>$value) { $fields[] = sprintf("%s = '%s'", $key, secure($value));} 
    $field_list = join(' AND ', $fields); unset($qWhere);
    return $field_list;
}
```

Is this the correct way or may it be achieved more clean and profesionally?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it looks pretty good; I like it. I assume `secure()` protects from sql injection. I don't really see anything I would change.

You *could* take braces out of the for loop since its one statement, but that's no biggy

```
foreach ($qWhere as $key=>$value)
    $fields[] = sprintf("%s = '%s'", $key, secure($value));
```

Comment: @yahyaE Np. I gotta say, I really like the way you built your query. +1 to your question. I will use this in the future (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8023461/where-field1-field2-field3-like-my-own-string/8023486#8023486)

Comment: thanks for kind words. Hope to learn something more from you.